# I get an error in my token validation function in golang

Tags: go, jwt

my code:

```
func ValidateToken(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    token, err := request.ParseFromRequestWithClaims(r, request.OAuth2Extractor, &models.Claim{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return publicKey, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Invalid Token")
        return
    }
    if token.Valid {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "welcome to the system")
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "your token is not valid")
    }
}
```

I have problem:

```
cannot use func literal (type func(*"github.com/tokens/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".Token) (interface {}, error)) as type "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".Keyfunc in argument to request.ParseFromRequestWithClaims
```

Comment: How do you import `jwt-go` in this file?

Comment: It seems your importing `*jwt.Token` from a vendor folder while the `request.ParseFromRequestWithClaims` func is imported from the GOPATH. import both of them from the vendor folder. By the way, `request.ParseFromRequestWithClaims` is deprecated. As mentioned in the source code, use `ParseFromRequest` and the `WithClaims` option